# Is it possible to manually sculpt a specific face in Blender ultra-accurately?

Tags: sculpting

I mean very accurately (over weeks if necessary) to match a specific face so that it looks as accurate as if done with a 3d scanner and you can identify the person clearly?  For example, like the object below.  This question is probably very opinion-based.  But if possible, I will consider practising and training to become that good.  If not possible, then you have saved me a lot of time and frustration.[image]

Comment: Artists can create lifelike portraits from wax, clay, even stone and in 3D. This depends on your skill level. If you have no artistic background at all, I would say it will take you about 3-5 years of dedicated work and practice to reach the leve you describe

Answer (score 3):

In theory, yes, if you have enough reference material and time, it would be possible. The end result is after all basically just a mesh and some textures, independent opf the method used to create it. However it takes a **lot** of skill to create lifelike copies of human faces, so if you intend to learn to do this yourself, expect to put in a lot of effort and experience a lot of frustration before you get something that looks reasonably good.

Its also worth noting that 3d scans also generally need a fair bit of manual work to get the best results, for example the image you have included has a number of artifacts including the eyebrows (which should probably be replaced with particle hair for a  more realistic reproduction.